# How to delete documents in a collection based on number of documents limit?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a command via Mongoose such that if more than a certain number of records exist in a collection that they're deleted?

I don't want to query my collection, sort by date, and then parse document by document to accomplish something that may already be a part of a more efficient Mongoose delete command.

Comment: Here are features of MongoDB which can be considered: [TTL Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/index.html) and [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/index.html). Mongoose has these features. You can also lookup about Capped Collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose middlewares specially in this case you can use `post` middleware. This middleware can be triggered after each insert and check the limit and do what you want.

From [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post):

```js
schema.post('save', function(doc) {
  console.log('%s has been saved', doc._id);
});
```